# Rate of growth of $a$ in $f(x) = \frac{\ln(ax)}{x}$ causing movement of extrema

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

**Problem description**

Look at the function $f(x) = \frac{\ln(ax)}{x}$ on a cartesian system with steps of 1cm on both axes.

a) Show that $f$ has a local maximum for $x = \frac ea$.

b) When $a$ increases, the local maximum will approach zero. Assume that $a$ increases at a rate of 2cm/min. How fast will the maximum horizontally approach zero?

c) There is a position $(x, y)$ such that the maximum approaches $0$ at the same rate, but oppositely directed. Find this $(x, y)$.

**My attempt**

I've solved a) using basic differentiation, and found that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{1-\ln(ax)}{x^2}$. This expression evaluates to $0$ when $x=\frac ea$ and $a\neq0$.

On b and c, I'm completely stumped. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

a) The derivative of $f$ is zero at $x=e/a$, and its second derivative is nonpositive at this point. Hence $f$ has a local maxima at $x=e/a$.

b) Consider $g\left(a\right)=e/a$. As $a\rightarrow\infty$, $g\left(a\right)\rightarrow0$, as noted in the problem description. The rate at which $g$ changes w.r.t. $a$ is not constant, it is $g^{\prime}\left(a\right)=-e/a^{2}$.

c) The local maxima found in (a) is the only maxima for values of $x>0$. The logarithm takes on complex values for $x<0$. See the image below:

[image]

Whoever is teaching you calculus does not know what they are doing...